# How can I delete presets in Lightroom 3?

Tags: lightroom, software, presets

How do you delete an unwanted preset in Lightroom 3 that you have in your saved presets?

Comment: Do you mean the factory presets or ones you've added?  I don't think you can remove the factory ones, but right-click, delete ought to work on the rest

Answer (score 2):

FYI, [this article from Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/preference-file-locations-lighroom-3.html) documents the file location of these presets:

> Installed and custom presets and templates have filenames ending in
>   .lrtemplate and are located in folders under the Users/[user
>   name]/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Lightroom folder.

[Another link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS2A36C507-E076-4b14-AAC3-87852595D175.html) (for LR4, but I presume this also holds true for LR3) confirms that "factory" or built-in presets cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried right clicking to delete @MikeW and no it's not the presets that come with LR, it's the others of added to it. Just want to narrow them down. Way too many ones I got for free that I don't use or don't like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all your presets in "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Lightroom\Develop Presets" and then delete which are not required. You will find two directories here as "Lightroom Presets" and "User Presets".

Comment: I'm using a mac.  And I did have the hard drive replaced.  I saved the presets I know to a USB but I don't know if I saved them to my external hard drive as well.  If I have them in lightroom still you would think I did b/c when I got my computer back I plugged it in.  Before taking it in though I delete my lots of my stuff on my hard drive....I can't seem to find the presets I have in lightroom.